# RegEx: Match string but only if of certain minimum length

Tags: regex

I have a huge number of text documents and try to extract a specific part from each of them. It always starts with "Item 7" at the beginning of a row and always ends with "Item 8" at the beginning of another row. I can find this part with the **regex**:

```
(^( *)Item 7(.+?)^( *)Item 8)
```

My two questions are:

1. There are potentially two parts that fit this description in each of my documents. I want to make sure that I only match the second one, which is also substantially longer.
2. How can I extract this part using regex in a "search and replace" query using notepad++?

I'm not sure if I am even using the right tool for this.

Thanks!

supplement:
With the help of the answers so far I did the following in notepad++.
Search for

.*(^( *)Item *7(?! *A)(?!.*^Item *7(?! *A))(.+?)^( *)(?=^Item *8)).*

Raplce with

$1

Thanks for your help so far. It works great with one excepction. I'm afraid I have to go into more detail: Most, but not all, documents I want to extract text from have a table of content. That's why I want to extract the second case of "Item 7 to Item 8", in case there are two. Also there is an Item 7A, in case you wonder about my code.

As I now realized, there is a number of documents, which have "Item 7" as a header on each page within the second case of item 7 to item 8. Thus, my code only matches the last page of Item 7 in some instances.

I thought a solution might be to only ignore cases of Item 7 to Item 8, if they have a certain minimum lenght. Specifically, only ignore cases of Item 7 to Item 8, if they have less than 120 signs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `(?m)^Item 7([\S\s]*?)(?=^Item 8)` But, you should show examples.

Comment: What if there are 2 blocks, but no ToC? Then, how can you tell what to grab? sorry, right now, this problem has no solutions until you formulate the context rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
^Item 7(?!.*^Item 7).*^Item 8
```

This finds the last of [Item 7 - Item 8] pairs in the document.

It works in Notepad++ 6.9.2 using the Find function, with the regular expression option, ***with `. matches newline` checked.***

NB: The `Find all in Current Document` button seems to use a different interpretation of the regular expression, apparently ignoring the negative look-ahead. This solution only works with the `Find Next` button.

Comment: I'm yet not sure why but this regex shows [inconsistent results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/olXcK.png) on a document with ~700 lines of one repeated block. [Notepad++ v6.9.2]

Comment: That seems a bug in Notepadd++. I have updated the regex which now seems to work with the `Find Next` button in bigger files as well, but the `Find All in Current Document` button seems to act differently.